# How to read just a line with an unknown quantity of ints from a text file onto an array (in C)

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a matrix from a .csr file (not exactly .csr, but based on the .csr format). The first line contains the dimensions of the matrix (x,y). The following line has an unknown number of floats, and the two following lines have the column and line where each of those floats read go.

I thought I could read the line from the file with fgets to get the whole line where the array is going to be read, then use sscanf on the string copyed by fgets. The problem is, sscanf doesn't read one by one the ints in the string. It reads the first int on the string many times over.

This is currently the code I wrote:

```c
int * readLineOfInts(FILE * file) { 
  if (!file) return NULL;

  int tmp, counter = 1, buff = 5, *v = malloc(buff * sizeof(int)); 
  char *str;
  fgets(str, 10000000, file);   string e salva em str
  while (sscanf(str,"%d", &tmp)) {  
    if (counter == buff) {    
      buff *= 2;
      v = realloc(v,buff * sizeof(int));
    }
    v[counter++] = tmp; 
  }
  v[0] = counter; 
 return v;

}
```

If the input file is

```c
5 5
0.2 0.6 0.4
2 3 3
2 2 3
```

The resulting array from reading the third line should be:
v={2,3,3}

But my code results in:
v={2,2,2}

Comment: In your while loop `str` stays the same, you're not changing the address so the loop does the same in every iteration

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `str`.

Comment: You need `char *str = malloc(10000000);`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your current code sample has comments that aren't properly commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`sscanf`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_sscanf.htm) function cannot keep track of what it has read from a string like the `fscanf` function because `fscanf` functions reads from a file stream which has an internal pointer that moves ahead.

To get the same effect with strings and `sscanf`, you need to manually move the pointer ahead. The following snippet can be used to read consecutively from the string.

```
int pos = 0;
int amount;
while (sscanf(str+pos,"%d %n", &tmp, &amount)) {
    pos += amount;
    // Rest of the code inside the while loop
}
```

Here instead of `str` we are using `str + pos`, the pos variable keeps track of how much you have read from the string and acts like a progress pointer. 
It is updated every time with the amount read in that call to `sscanf`. The `%n` format specifier lets us read how many characters were actually processed.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you are not allocating any memory for `str`. 
You can either use the size `10000000` (which is the size you pass to `fgets`) or use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) (but `getline` is not standard C).